# Fallback for using unicode with css

Tags: css, unicode

I was wondering if you could create a fallback when using unicode characters. See I got following css:

```
.icon-check:after {
    content:'\2714';
    color: green;
}
```

and one would have no support for this character, is there a way to just print 'yes' or something?

For fonts there it's easy , just like `p{font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;}`. But for the content attribute, there seems no way to create such a fallback.

N.B. I know there other possibilities like Font Awesome, Glyphicons and similar but I am just interested  if there is a fallback.

Comment: No, I don't think so. It is only the OS's problem that there is no such font, then the browser displays a holder character. There should not be a error event going on, thus it should be undetectable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is there a way to just print 'yes' or something?

Simple answer? **No**.

> I was wondering if you could create a fallback when using unicode
>   characters

Simple answer? **Yes...ish**.

The only fallback you can specify is on the font family, however you can use `@fontface` to [specify the unicode range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-range) of the font you're using.

> The unicode-range CSS descriptor sets the specific range of characters
>   to be downloaded from a font defined by @font-face and made available
>   for use on the current page.

There is a [great article on 24 Ways](http://24ways.org/2011/creating-custom-font-stacks-with-unicode-range/) which outlines how this can be done, you could for example, specify a font-family just for the character in question e.g.(from the article):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Ampersand';
    src: local('Baskerville'), local('Palatino'), local('Book Antiqua');
    unicode-range: U+26;
}
```

Then do:

```
.icon-check:after {
    content:'\26';
    color: green;
}
```

Nb. the above is for an ampersand but should give you an idea of one approach
.